# sql syntax error with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get the results pulled from the API inserted into a database. It returns a SQL error when the program is run. It seems I'm not having this sent in the right syntax and I cant seem to to get it to do so. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var replace = require ('Regexp')
var url = 'https://api.nicehash.com/api?method=stats.provider.workers&addr=3Hwm6i8aefzHhJTbEGtSJeR6tZCJXqY7EN';

//connect to database
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx',
    table: 'workerstats'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});


const requestHandler = (request, response) => {  
    response.end(workerstats)
}

request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } 
    else if (res.statusCode !== 200) 
    {
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    } 
    else {(!err && data && data.result && data.result.workers)

        var workerstats = JSON.stringify(data.result.workers);
        var wsclean = workerstats.replace(/[&\/\\#+()$~%'*?<>{}]/g,'')
                                 .replace(/"a":/g,'');
    };

    console.log(wsclean);

    var sql = "INSERT INTO 'workerstats' (workers, accepted, uptime, xnsub, difficulty, zone, algo) ?", wsclean;

    con.query(sql, [workerstats], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
    }
    );

})
```

EDIT: Okay so after hours of tinkering, I 'think' I've made progress, but that silly A: has got me again. Its viewing as an object, and SQL is rejecting it. Though I thought (Though obviously improperly) I converted it to string. This is the amended code. Please forgive the formatting, it wasnt playing nice.

```
request.get({
url: url,
json: true,
headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
}, (err, res, data) => {
if (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
}
else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
}
else {
    (!err && data && data.result)

    var data = JSON.parse(data.result);
    var responseJson = JSON.stringify(data.response);
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET column=?', responseJson, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('data inserted');
    });

   }
});
```

It returns the following error:

> undefined:1
>       [object Object]
>       SyntaxError: unexpected token o in JSON at postion 1

Awesome. So somewhere I did something stupid, or improperly. In the raw API that object Object appears like: {"a":"158.01"} - How do I convert that to a string, when I thought I already did? Id also like to eliminate the 'a' and the ':' entirely as im not sure how to process that into SQL and its unneeded information.

Comment: Going by the syntax you're sending one string `wsclean` to 7 columns.

Comment: I think I addressed that in this update I just put up but I'm still having issues with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup `json: true` in the request option, You no longer have to perform `JSON.parse(data.result)`, you directly access the data as object. Therefore the error, because `JSON.parse({ a: 1})` call the toString method, and the result `[object Object]` its not valid JSON.

Note: You convert the `data.result.workers` to a string. I think you should leave it as an array for it to work.

```
con.query(sql, data.result.workers, function (err, result)
```

Comment: I had tried that and it does advance the error further down the line, however if you pull the api it includes a bit of garbage I dont want in there and that SQL doesnt like. In the api it will also include "a:" to indicate accepted speed. This is redundant as this particular api call only shows accepted speed, additionally SQL seems to not know what to do with it. I had added all that other stuff previous to try to eliminate it to no avail.

Comment: I appreciate your insight - however I am very new to programing and I do not completely understand. Additional clarification would be helpful.